# C# Multiple picturebox initialisation issue

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am putting together an application that uses more than one picturebox on the GUI.  I have written custom events for each picturebox that are called on paint events.

Unfortunately, when the application runs, precisely one picturebox displays properly.  The others simply display as white boxes.  Whichever opicturebox happens to be added first in form.designer is the picturebox that displays properly, for the others their paint events are never triggered.  I have tried to get around this by calling various combinations of picturebox.refresh(), picturebox.update() and picturebox.invalidate() in the form constructor, to no avail.

Interestingly, when I associate a button press event with picturebox.refresh() and picturebox.update() and press the button once the program is running, the pictureboxes start behaving as normal - the paint event is called and the image updates.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get all of the pictureboxes to display properly on initialisation?

Code snippets that may be useful:

Paint code for the pictureboxes:

```
private void PictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    paintPictureBox(e, PictureBox1, currentImage[0]);
}

private void paintPictureBox(PaintEventArgs e, PictureBox picBox,ImageObject c)
{
    try
    {
        Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 14);
        //Get bitmap
        Bitmap imageToDisplay = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(c.ImageFile));
        //resize smallest dimension to 200
        if (imageToDisplay.Height > imageToDisplay.Width)
        {
            imageToDisplay = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(c.ImageFile), 200, 200 * imageToDisplay.Height / imageToDisplay.Width);
        }
        else
        {
            imageToDisplay = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(c.ImageFile), 200 * imageToDisplay.Width / imageToDisplay.Height, 200);
        }
        //crop anything outside of 200x200
        imageToDisplay = imageToDisplay.Clone(new Rectangle(Math.Max((imageToDisplay.Width - 200) / 2, 0), Math.Max((imageToDisplay.Height - 200) / 2, 0), 200, 200), imageToDisplay.PixelFormat);
        //now draw it
        picBox.Image = imageToDisplay;  
        //add the name
        e.Graphics.DrawString(c.Name, myFont, Brushes.Maroon, new Point(2, 200));
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Could not display image successfully\n" + E.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Code from form.designer:

```
    //This one displays correctly on initialisation
    this.Controls.Add(this.PictureBox0);
    //These two do not
    this.Controls.Add(this.PictureBox1);
    this.Controls.Add(this.PictureBox2);
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.PictureBox0)).EndInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.PictureBox1)).EndInit();
    ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.PictureBox2)).EndInit();
```

Code for button press that makes pictureboxes display correctly (after initialisation):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Refresh the picture boxes
    foreach (PictureBox pb in this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
    {
        pb.Refresh();
        pb.Update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Paint` event is raised every time your window needs to be repainted.  For example, if another window is being dragged over the top of yours, the `Paint` event will be raised several times per second.  Hence it is important that your `paintPictureBox` function does nothing but paint.

The problem is that `paintPictureBox` is continually reinitialising the bitmap but not actually drawing it.  Additionally, you are reading from the disk and creating several bitmaps every time you paint.  This is slow and uses gobs of memory.

Instead, you should initialise each picture box's `Image` property once, when the form loads.  Each picture box will then take care of drawing its own bitmap.  Your paint event should do nothing but draw the picture name.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - it has enabled me to solve the problem.  I am now only changing the bitmap when required, not every time the paint method is called, and the text is the only thing refreshed on paint.  Now all pictureboxes initialise correctly.  I'm not sure I completely understand why it did not work before - in what way was the method initialising the bitmap but not drawing it?

Comment: You draw a bitmap by calling a function like `Graphics.DrawImage`.  Setting the `Image` property on a picture box doesn't draw anything - it tells the picture box to take care of drawing the bitmap in the future.